# use apt-get install python packages in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, pandas, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

my `gitlab-ci.yml` I install python-pandas but I can't use it from python.

```
$ cat .gitlab-ci.yml
image: python:2

test:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-pip python-pandas
  - ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  - python -c 'import pandas'
```

The runner failed with this message::

```
 $ python -c 'import pandas'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named pandas
  ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

I try to not install pandas with pip as requirement (old pandas lib is enought)
And very much would like to understand why python packages are not exposed ? this look like an implicit virtualenv !?

Comment: did you try to install old version with `pip` using ie. `pandas==0.17`

Comment: BTW: use `python -V` to check if you use Python 2 or 3.

Comment: the main reason is to speed up the build in debug phase, that's way I would like to stay with apt-get installs

Comment: right now I updated pandas to 0.19.2 (Linux Mint based on Ubuntu) using `pip` and it went fast - I think `pip` was using precompiled modules

Comment: I'd recommend you to create your own Docker image based on `python:2` and having all the extra packages installed.  This way you can test it before use in CI, you would speed up the tests and you would avoid any surprises.

Comment: @tmt how to say in .gitlab-ci.yml to use my own Docker image available on my registry gitlab.corp.com ?

Comment: In case of a private registry it would be `image: gitlab.corp.com:5000/your-python-image:latest`.

Answer (score 12):

You should create a virtualvenv in `before_script`:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y python
  - apt-get -qq update
  - apt-get -qq install -y python python-virtualenv python-pip
  - virtualenv venv
  - . venv/bin/activate
  - python -V
  - pip install pandas
```